# How to change Show on Viewer Panel to Do Not Show on parameter fields in a report file?

Tags: .net, powershell, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a powershell script to change the value option named Show on Viewer Panel to Do not show for a parameter field.  In Crystal Designer 2016, I can open the field explorer > Parameter Fields.  Then, open the parameter field properties.  Show on Viewer Panel appears under value options.  I can change the value there.

I want to leave the other value options as is after changing Show on Viewer Panel.

Using powershell, I'm able to load a rpt file, find the parameter, and see the option set in a enumeration property named ParameterFieldUsage2.  I've tried several different tactics to try to change that enumeration but failed to do so.  Research online and the errors I see makes me believe that that property is read only.

After this is resolved, I plan to run a couple loops to update many reports and parameters fields.   Do you have any advice on what to try next or how to research this further?

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('CrystalDecisions.Shared')
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine')  

$report = New-Object CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
$report.Load('.\Exp.rpt')

$report.ParameterFields|%{$_.ParameterFieldName}

($report.ParameterFields|? name -like 'Print*').ParameterFieldUsage2 = `
"DoNotShow"
<#
Exception setting "ParameterFieldUsage2": "Cannot convert value "DoNotShow" to 
type "CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFieldUsage2". Error: "Unable to match the 
identifier name DoNotShow to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following 
enumerator names and try again:
Unknown, InUse, NotInUse, CurrentValuesProvidedByServer, ShowOnPanel, 
EditableOnPanel, DataFetching, IsLinked""
#>

$field = $report.ParameterFields|? name -like 'Print*'
$field.ParameterFieldUsage2 = [CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFieldUsage2]::InUse
<#
Exception setting "ParameterFieldUsage2": "Not Supported."
  SetValueInvocationException
#>
```